# Help with functional block program from ladder logic

Tags: function, ladder

I'm learning some basic functional block diagram programming

and I'm trying to convert this ladder logic into block diagram but I don't know how because my book doesn't cover this.

[image]

Can someone please show me how this looks in function block diagram please? Once I see this I'll be able to do the rest based off that since I know how to do other ones.

Comment: I'm sure your book does cover turning ladder diagrams into block diagrams.  Just not this one.  We don't do your homework for you!  Try and we will help.  But homework with no attempt to solve is closed.

Comment: So your book doesn't cover basic PLC logic symbols? Are you able to write the logic statement (not the block diagram) of this ladder diagram?

Comment: @RohatKılıç yeah it doesn't. can you recommend me a book that explains this?

Comment: I cannot recommend any book but there are tons of online tutorials that can be found by googling "ladder diagram examples" or "ladder diagram tutorial" or "ladder diagram logic" etc. And a hint: Connecting in parallel means LOGIC OR, and connecting in series means LOGIC AND.

Comment: Sorry I did my homework many years ago, as much as I hated it I learned a lot. I do not want to spoil that privilege for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint for now.

Break it down.

```
  A      B      C      D        E
-| |----| |----| |----| |------(S)

  A      E                      F
-| |----|/|--------------------( )
```

Can you work it out now? Update your question and we'll help you along.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. That hint was all I needed. I was confused if it was OR or not at first.

Comment: OK, but post your solution in your original question and we can confirm it for you.